# gitlab-ci: run manual jobs automatically on tags

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

Assuming this stripped down gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
stages:
  - tests
  - build_release
  - deploy
prepare-cache:
  stage: tests
    - "echo prepare some general stuff"
build_release_frontend:
  stage: build_release
  when: manual
  needs:
    - prepare-cache
  script:
    - "echo do a frontend build"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - assets
    when: always
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  needs:
    - build_release_frontend
  script:
    - "echo do a release"
```

How can i change the `build_release_frontend`-job to

- always can be run manually
- run automatically when someone creates a tag?

I already tried

```
build_release_frontend:
  stage: build_release
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: always
    - when: manual
  needs:
    - prepare-cache
```

but this gives me two pipelines: one of them failing with `"build_release_frontend" job needs 'prepare-cache' job, but 'prepare-cache' is not in any previous stage` with zero containing jobs and another pipeline running as before the change.

Comment: Doesnt the prepare-cache job run in every stage? what version of gitlab are you using? does the build_release_frontend always require prepare-cache?

Comment: prepare-cache runs in a stage before build_release_frontend. We use GitLab Community Edition v16.3.0. Yes, prepare-cache is always required to build frontend.

Comment: but whats the rules statement for prepare-cache as it must have some other rules that results in thta job not being triggered and giving you the error `"build_release_frontend" job needs 'prepare-cache' job, but 'prepare-cache' is not in any previous stage`